# Update each row for Each corresponding select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns some old `MemberShipIDs`

```
select cst.MembershipID from Contestant cst
inner join User usr on usr.ID = cst.ID and usr.TypeOfUser = 0
order by usr.CreatedOn
```

And I have another query which will return some new updated `MemberShipIDs`

```
select 
'CON' + '-' + convert(nvarchar(255), 
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by CreatedOn)) + '-' 
+ Right(Year(usr.CreatedOn),2)
from Contestant cst
inner join [dbo].[User] usr on usr.ID = cst.ID and usr.TypeOfUser = 0
```

Now, I want update the old `MemberShipID` value with the new `MemberShipID` value
for each matching

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: please add your tables and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` in an `update`.  This allows you to calculate the new value in a subquery or CTE and to assign it in the `update`:

```
update cst
    set MembershipId = newval.newMembershipId
from Contestant cst join
     (select cst.MembershipID,
             'CON' + '-' + convert(nvarchar(255), ROW_NUMBER() over(order by CreatedOn)) + '-' + Right(Year(usr.CreatedOn),2) as newMembershipId
      from Contestant cst inner join
           [dbo].[User] usr
           on usr.ID = cst.ID and usr.TypeOfUser = 0
      ) newval
      on cst.MembershipID = newval.MembershipID;
```